# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Se que hay muchas preguntas de este tema. He navegado bastante y al momento no encontrado algo que lo solucione.

El problema es que pese a que `FormsModule` ha sido importado sigue marcando el mismo error.

**AppModule.ts**

```
   import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
    ....

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
....
```

Luego en html del template algo como esto:

```
<div class="ibox login-content">
<div class="text-center">
    <span class="auth-head-icon"><i class="la la-user"></i></span>
</div>
<form class="ibox-body" id="login-form" action="javascript:;" method="POST">
    <h4 class="font-strong text-center mb-5">LOG IN</h4>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-line" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" required placeholder="Email"/>

    </div>
</form>
```

**loginComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    **model: any = {};**
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        this.authenticationService.logout();

        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
}
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes mostrar el archivo Ts para ver como tienes declarado model

Comment: listo @IDanny7 he agredado el componenet

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Angular estás utilizando??

Comment: Actualizaste angular? Intenta elimando `node_modules`, seguido de `npm install` Si actualizaste a angular 10 desde angular < 9 tienes que actualizar las librerias a angular 10.

Answer (score 3):

Me pasó lo mismo.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**:

El problema que tenía era que debía importar `FormsModule` en el archivo `.module.ts` más cercano al componente con el error.

[image: Estructura de carpetas de proyecto Angular]

El `<input>` y el error estaban en `app/shared/outlined-field/outlined-field.component.html`, y yo tenía correctamente importado `FormsModule` en `app/app.module.ts`.

Mi solución fue importar (también?) `FormsModule` en `app/shared/shared.module.ts` que era el archivo `.module.ts` más cercano a mi componente.

**ORIGINAL:**

*(Esta respuesta está erronea, el uso correcto es `[(ngModel)]` como dice [Legna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176325/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input/387397?noredirect=1#comment694015_387397), si bien el *error desaparece*, el problema no y el `ngModel` sigue sin funcionar.)*

> El problema era que estaba usando `[(ngModel)]` en vez de
> `([ngModel])`.

Comment: El uso correcto es `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Tienes razón, mi error. Sin embargo, si revisas la edición de mi respuesta, finalmente encontré la solución a mi problema